# Concurrent update elastic index by java client and some update lost

Tags: elasticsearch

When concurrent execute update elastic index by java client, at final it seems lost some update. For example I hava an index {"count":0} at first, then there are 10 thread to incremnt count by 1, at final I expecte the count is 10, but actually I found  it less than 10. My demo code is :

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
// create index
client.prepareIndex(index, type, id)
.setSource(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject().field("count", 0).endObject())
.execute().get();

// multi thread update
int count = 10;
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
service.execute(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
   try {
       client.prepareUpdate(index, type, id)
        .setScript("ctx._source.count += 1", ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE).execute();

     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
});
}

// check result
latch.await();
service.shutdown();
GetResponse getResponse = client.prepareGet(index, type, id).execute().get();

System.out.println(getResponse.getSourceAsString());
```

So where these lost update?

========================================================

Information supplementary

Actually don't need make concurrent in client side, actually sequential execute also can have the same effect,

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  client.prepareUpdate(index, type, id)
      .setScript("ctx._source.count += 1", ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE).execute();
}
```

By wireshark I found there are exception of version conflict happend.

[image]

So now I am very confused of how server side process client reuqest? Why in sequential situation still cannot get right result?

Answer (score 0):

By default, every `*RequestBuilder` has a timeout which is the time to wait if the index/update/delete operation can't be performed immediately.

So theoretically it's possible that some of your updates are still pending and were not executed. Try to force refresh the index with the following method:

```
client.prepareUpdate(index, type, id)
   .setScript("ctx._source.count += 1", ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE)
   .setRefresh(true)
   .execute()
   .actionGet();
```

Comment: Thanks! Please see my supplemnetary info.